# Redirect Symfony2 LogoutSuccessHandler to original logout target

Tags: php, symfony

I need to modify my user object on logout. To do this, I have a security.yml that contains the following (amongst other things) -

```
#...
    logout:
        success_handler: my.logout_success_handler
        target: /
#...
```

...this defines a logout success handler, which is defined in services.yml like this -

```
   my.security.logout_success_handler:
       class: My\Security\LogoutSuccessHandler
       arguments: ["@security.context", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]
```

...finally, the business-end of my handler is like this -

```
// ...
public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
{

    $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

    // ... do stuff with the user object....
    $this->em->flush();

    // now what?

}
// ...
```

So, where it says "now what?" I understand that I need to return a Response object. Ideally I want that response object to redirect the user to whatever is defined in logout.target in the security.yml.

Is there an easy way I can query that? Or, even better, is there another way of doing this kind of thing that doesn't require me to get involved with the request/response objects at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I think I've figured out the right answer -

Rather than implementing `LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface` and configuring a `logout.success_handler`, my security.yml now looks like this -

```
# ...
logout:
    handlers: [my.bundle.security.logout_handler]
# ...
```

...and I'm implementing `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutHandlerInterface`. Confusing naming, but this seems to be the preferred way of doing post-logout operations without having to get involved with the response object. My implementation looks like this -

```
namespace My\Bundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/**
 * Do post logout stuff
 */
class LogoutHandler implements LogoutHandlerInterface
{

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {

        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Do post logout stuff
     */
    public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $authToken)
    {
        $user = $authToken->getUser();

        // do stuff with the user object...
        $this->em->flush();

        return $response;
    }
}
```

...as you can see, the `LogoutHandlerInterface` provides a pre-made `$response` object that I can just return when I'm finished.

Comment: The difference here is that you are always manipulating your user, even if logout  isnt successful.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the `LogoutHandler`(s) are called *after* the `LogoutSuccessHandler`, which would imply that logout success is guaranteed to happen. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/f828aee7f749009a574eee0a1ad5bfd092b0d488/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/LogoutListener.php#L108-L118

Comment: Only if it is bailing if its not successful.

Answer (score 8):

You could define your target as a parameter in your `parameters.yml` or `config.yml`:

```
parameters:
    logout.target: /
```

And then reference this value in your `security.yml`:

```
    logout:
        success_handler: my.logout_success_handler
        target: %logout.target%
```

And/or inject it into your logout handler:

```
    my.security.logout_success_handler:
        class: My\Security\LogoutSuccessHandler
        arguments: ["@security.context", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", %logout.target%]
```

And return a `RedirectResponse` with this value:

```
// Assign the 3. constructor parameter to the instance variable $logoutTarget

public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
{
    // ...

    return new RedirectResponse($this->logoutTarget);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use composition and inject the default `LogoutSuccessHandler` into your object and call the `onLogoutSucces` method on it.

The following pseudu code shows the idea of doing it.

```
class MyLogoutSuccessHandler implements \LogoutSuccessHandler
{
    protected $original;

    public function __construct(OriginalLogoutSuccesHandler $original)
    {
        $this->original = $original;
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        // do stuf your want and delegate to the original
        return $this->original->onLogoutSuccess($request);
    }
}
```

This is also the way `HttpKernelInterface` works in StackPHP and when you use `HttpCache` in your application.

Hopefully this helps, happy coding :)

Comment: That's very interesting, and it's let me to what I think is probably the right answer, which I'll post now...

Comment: The original handler class is actually `DefaultLogoutSuccessHandler`

Comment: What's the service name to inject in the services.yml?