# Symfony2 how to invalidate all the session attributes

Tags: symfony, session, logout

In my `Symfony2` project i have a `logout` button which redirect to the index page but when i click the `Login` button it connects directly without asking me for `user` and `password`.

how can i validate all `session attributes`, so if i `login` again it should ask me for `user` and `password`

this is my `logout` Action:

```
public function logoutAction(Request $request)
    {    
        $this->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
        $this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();

        $url = $this->generateUrl('my_route');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        $response->headers->clearCookie('PHPSESSID');
        $response->send();
        return $response;
    }
```

here's the **security.yml**:

```
security:

    encoders:
        Envivio\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:        
        mine:
            id: ib_user.oauth_user_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false        

        main:
            anonymous: true
            pattern: ^/
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    salesforce: "/login/check-salesforce"
                login_path:   /login
                #use_forward:  false
                failure_path: /login
                default_target_path: /upload
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: ib_user.oauth_user_provider                
            remember_me:
                key:     "%secret%"


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }       
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: is your logout action route matches with your firewall pattern ?

Comment: yes it match perfectly

Comment: check what do you still have inside your session parameters ?

Comment: how can i check the session parameters ??

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
$this->get('session')->clear();
```

or

```
$session = $this->get('session');
$ses_vars = $session->all();
foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
    $session->remove($key);
}
```

It may also be a cookie problem check your cookies in the response->headers then try clearing it with that function :

http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ResponseHeaderBag.html#method_clearCookie

## Edit :

Since you have remember me enabledyou need to clear that cookie too otherwise the next request you do will reauthenticate the user, you can specify a name for the cookie :

```
  #security.yml
    
    remember_me:
             name: "%session.remember_me.name%"
```

add in parameters.yml the name of the cookie

```
parameters:
    session.remember_me.name: EXTSESS
```

then in your controller logout action :

```
$response = $this->redirectToRoute('homepageroute'); //redirect prepare the route to redirect
$this->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
$remember_sess_name = $this->container->getParameter('session.remember_me.name');

$response->headers->clearCookie($remember_sess_name);

return $response;
```

it should work now. if this doesn't then ALT+F4 :D

Comment: i tried to clear the session with this method 
`$this->get('request')->cookies->remove("PHPSESSID");`
but it's not working, and i tried different method but it doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: did you try what i said? because you say you tried $this->get('request')->cookies->remove("PHPSESSID"); but this is not what i recommanded, you also may have a problem in your configuration, try to look for something missing or a typo , edit your question with the security yml also

Comment: the answer is edited.
i tried all you told me but it doesn't work

Comment: what do you still have in your session after clearing it? and also the cookies, what inside?

Comment: still not working, i also tried to disable `remember_me` in `security.yml` but it doesn't work

Comment: var dump your cookies and session to see what is it still inside related with auths

Comment: i did it and all the attribute of session was cleared but the cookies still has this value :  `["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "tla1knj605s4klg5lm9md5ve13"`

Comment: i cleared the cookie by this function and it's still not working: 
`$response->headers->clearCookie('PHPSESSID');`

Comment: and you use that response as a return ?

Comment: yes i used `RedirectResponse` object : i edited my  `logoutAction`

Comment: btw you will always have a session even for anonymous users so clearing it will just create another one so it will never really be removed, your problem is somewhere else... are you using some kind of http login ? your browser may keep your username and password and every request it log you in automatically , test this using private browsing or some other browser which you didnt use before

Comment: i tried another web browser and i have the same result

Comment: try to review your configuration, i never had this problem before normally it should be working... otherwise try to post your issue in symfony's github you may get more help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it manually. The Symfony2 firewall can perform a logout like this:

> ```
> # app/config/security.yml
> security:
>     firewalls:
>         secured_area:
>             # ...
>             logout:
>                 path:   /logout
>                 target: /
>     # ...
> ```
>
> Next, you'll need to create a route for this URL (but not a
>   controller):
>
> ```
> # app/config/routing.yml
> logout:
>     path:   /logout
> ```
>
> And that's it! By sending a user to /logout (or whatever you configure
>   the path to be), Symfony will un-authenticate the current user.
>
> Once the user has been logged out, they will be redirected to whatever
>   path is defined by the target parameter above (e.g. the homepage).

Link to the related doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#logout

Comment: but the `route` that i want to redirect after `logout ` is `my_home_page` and it has 2 `parameters`, how can i set parameters in `target path` ?

Comment: You can't at least not easily. Either build a new route `after_logout` and redirect to the route you want the user to land after logout or use a [custom logout handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21835783/1847340)

Comment: Or you can set 2 default values on that route, if it's feasible.

Comment: it's not possible, the parameters will change, it should be general

Comment: @ihssan so use an 'after-logout' redirect as suggested by ferdynator