# Can't get the logout action sonata-project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-security

This is my security.yml file

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: project_frontend_main_index
        logout: 
            path: project_frontend_main_logout
            anonymous: true

access_control: 
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN } 
    - { path: ^/alerts*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

My question is The problem is with logout, I can't access logout function in the Main controller. I get this error when i click "logout" You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.

Comment: Please, add details and ask a question.

Comment: My question is why I can not access the logout action on the Main controller

Comment: Can you provide your access_control parameters (should be at the bottom of this file) ?

Comment: access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/alerts*, role: ROLE_USER }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this on the top of your `access_control` :

```
- { path: ^/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Also, you have to add the `target` for the `logout` (where the user will be redirected :

```
logout: 
    path: project_frontend_main_logout
    target: / #or a specific public route
```

If none of this works, use the default configuration for a sonata project that can be found [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html) :

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:      .*
            form-login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still get the error "You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration."

Comment: Ok, try adding the `target` for the logout then (see my edit)

Comment: I try adding "target" but still getting the same error

Comment: Ok, maybe you could use the default configuration ?

Comment: Yes it works if I use the default configuration, but I want when a user click"log out" to get that action and update their online status on the database, so I need to call the specific  function something like this logoutAction()(..update set online =0 "}

Comment: That is what I meant by "ask a question". You should have ask this in the first place. Anyway, you can find a way to [do this with logout handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835509/redirect-symfony2-logoutsuccesshandler-to-original-logout-target)

Answer (score 0):

Remove anonymous : true, or atleast make it false. This will solve your issue.

Comment: I try that, still not working. I get the same error "You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration."