# Display flash messages after login/logout

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, flash-message

I have been following [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) from the Symfony Book to manage my users.

Now, I would like to set a flash message after the login has succeeded OR if somebody attempts to access a forbidden area.

What I understand is that authentication and authorization are not managed inside controllers. As a consequence, I do not know where to put my code to display a simple "Sorry, you are not connected" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will take some time and some coding just to display a simple message. If you want to do it by Symfony way you should look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration) security configuration first, especially these ones:

1. `entry_point` (under firewall) - which usually redirects users to login page whenever they try to access the secured pages. You can set flash messages here.
2. `success_handler` under `form_login` (if you're using it) to show your successful login message
3. `success_handler` under `logout` to show your logout message

Some references:

- [SecurityBundle Configuration ("security")](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)
- [Symfony2: why access_denied_handler doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968354/symfony2-why-access-denied-handler-doesnt-work)
- [What is the best way to notify a user after an access_control rule redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428987/what-is-the-best-way-to-notify-a-user-after-an-access-control-rule-redirects)
- [Redirect Symfony2 LogoutSuccessHandler to original logout target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835509/redirect-symfony2-logoutsuccesshandler-to-original-logout-target)
- [Adding a Flash Message](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep2/flash-message)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think I shall use the `success_handler` method. Now I am thinking about creating a new service named FlashMessages that would handle most flash messages used in my application.

But for now I am struggling to create and register that service.

Comment: @LeBarde It's very simple to create and use services. Read about them [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

Comment: Thanks @xurshid29 for your answer. Now I have my services. Now I have a `LoginSuccessHandler` service. But here `$request->getUser()` is `null` inside the `onAuthenticationSuccess()` method. I cannot understand why. Going on searching...

Comment: OK I have succeeded by injecting `"@security.token_storage"` in my service. Afterwhat I call a `$this->security->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername()`. fffff...

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `SecurityContext` from your `Controller`. So, assuming your *forbidden area* require a role `SOME_ROLE`, you can do something like:

```
if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('SOME_ROLE')) {
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Access forbidden');
    // maybe return a RedirectResponse to another page the user can access...
}
```

Note that the `SecurityContext` has been deprecated since Symfony 2.6. It will still work, but if you want to learn how to adapt to future versions, you can check [this](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements).

As for the messages when users are/aren't logged in, you can use the `AuthorizationChecker`, very similar to the previous one:

```
if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    // Add flash message here...
}
```

You can find more information [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully).